# mysql two different queries into two different html tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run two different mysql queries and output results into two different html tables. I'm opening one DB connection and fetching two entirely different result sets.

I have one page that I want to show two different 's in the page, each table is the results from different query.

```
echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>";                  
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>Last</th><th>First</th><th>MDC</th><th>RADIO</th><th>EPCR</th><th>FH</th>";
echo "</tr></thead></table>";   

while ($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['LAST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['FIRST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['MDC']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['RADIO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['ePCR']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['Firehouse']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";                       

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed'>";                  
echo "<thead><tr>";
echo "<th>USERNAME</th><th>CLASSNAME</th><th>DATE COMPLETED</th>";
echo "</tr></thead></table>";


while ($rowB = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tbody><tr>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['UserName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['ClassName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['DateCompleted']."</td>";
}
echo "</tr></tbody></table>";

mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

here is my query:

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");



$selected = mysql_select_db("tech_training",$dbhandle) 
or die("Could not select examples");


$result = mysql_query("SELECT LastName AS LAST, FirstName AS FIRST,
MAX(IF(`ClassName`='MDC (Intro)', DATE_FORMAT(`DateCompleted`, '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL)) AS 'MDC', 
MAX(IF(`ClassName`='800 MHz Radio (Intro)', DATE_FORMAT(`DateCompleted`, '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL)) AS 'RADIO',
MAX(IF(`ClassName`='ePCR (Intro)', DATE_FORMAT(`DateCompleted`, '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL)) AS 'ePCR',
MAX(IF(`ClassName`='Firehouse (Incident)', DATE_FORMAT(`DateCompleted`, '%m/%d/%Y'), NULL)) AS 'Firehouse'
FROM    EnrollmentsTbl INNER JOIN UsersDataTbl ON EnrollmentsTbl.UserName = UsersDataTbl.UserName
GROUP BY EnrollmentsTbl.UserName 
ORDER BY LastName
LIMIT 20;"); 


//execute the second SQL query and return records
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT UserName, ClassName, DateCompleted FROM EnrollmentsTbl LIMIT 10;");
```

Comment: And?  Please edit your post and clarify what your problem is, and ask a question.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated. Don't use it anymore!!

Comment: I'm getting the results from both `mysql_fetch_array` The first is formatted correctly, the second shows the results run together no table formatting?

Comment: Edit your question with the Query.

Comment: you shouldn't have `tbody` inside your while if you are getting more than 1 row back otherwise you will have multiple `tbodys` open and only 1 close.

Comment: so why are the results displayed fine in the first table and no table in the second?

Comment: Use "View source" in your browser, and if you don't see where the problems are, use an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/) that will show you where the HTML errors are.

Comment: thanks - got it ! it was the </table> in the top of each table... wow dumb typo.

Comment: BarclayVision because Chrome and other browsers have crazy algorithms that try to rebuild or fix broken HTML. That might be the reason one of the tables looks fine. But in reality your browser is doing the heavy lifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere at the top of the page, or preferably use an include statement since according to PSR 1 you should not have output mixed with functions/classes.

Use **PDO** and here is an example.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$rowA = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table2');
$rowB = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**ANSWER**

```
echo "<tbody>"; //this is outside
while ($rowB = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['UserName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['ClassName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowB['DateCompleted']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";// MOVE THIS INSIDE THE LOOP!!!

}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

other loop:

```
echo "<tbody>"; //outide
while ($rowA = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['LAST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['FIRST']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['MDC']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['RADIO']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['ePCR']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$rowA['Firehouse']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; //move end row here
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
//you have some array
$result = [];

echo "<table>" // you only want one of these
foreach($results as $rows){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>data</td><td> mode data </td>";
    echo "</tr>"; close row each time
}
echo "</table>" //close it ONLY ONCE!
```

**Recommendation**

Proper and readable formatting would of saved you. EX:

```
  echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>
      <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Last</th><th>First</th><th>MDC</th><th>RADIO</th><th>EPCR</th><th>FH</th></tr>
      </thead>
  </table>";
```

OR:

```
$table = <<<HTML
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed'>
  <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Last</th><th>First</th><th>MDC</th><th>RADIO</th><th>EPCR</th><th>FH</th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
HTML;
echo $table;
```

Comment: you know now what the question is??

Comment: thanks, but my issue seems to be the formatting of the results, the first is fine the second has no <tr>?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand?

Comment: You have to have a closing TR (Row) for every Loop.    So while (){ <tr> <some tds>  </ close TR > } close loop  </table> close table

Comment: thanks - got it ! it was the </table> in the top of each table... wow dumb typo.

Comment: I strongly recommend switching away from mysql_ to pdo or mysqli_ . I aslo recommend using heredocs strings for better formating